# ConfigurationManager.GetSection returns null when section type is a different assembly

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

I'm trying to read from a configuration section in app.config which has been added by way of a reference to NServiceBus.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="UnicastBusConfig"
                 type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
        <section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig"
                 type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
        <section name="TestConfig"
                 type="Console1.UnicastBusConfigSection, Console1" />
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"
                          sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error" />
    <UnicastBusConfig>
        <MessageEndpointMappings></MessageEndpointMappings>
    </UnicastBusConfig>
    <TestConfig>
        <MessageEndpointMappings></MessageEndpointMappings>
    </TestConfig>
</configuration>
```

I have the following classes defined for the `UnicastBusConfig` section:

```
public class UnicastBusConfigSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty(MessageEndPointMappingsName)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(MessageEndPointMappingsCollection), AddItemName = "add")]
    public MessageEndPointMappingsCollection MessageEndPointMappings { get { return (MessageEndPointMappingsCollection)base[MessageEndPointMappingsName]; } }
}

public class MessageEndPointMappingsCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new MessageEndPointMappingsElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((MessageEndPointMappingsElement)element).Messages;
    }

    public void Add(MessageEndPointMappingsElement element)
    {
        BaseAdd(element);
    }
}

public class MessageEndPointMappingsElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Messages", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Messages
    {
        get { return (string)this["Messages"]; }
        set { this["Messages"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("Endpoint", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Endpoint
    {
        get { return (string)this["Endpoint"]; }
        set { this["Endpoint"] = value; }
    }
}
```

When I call ConfigurationManager.GetSection for the UnicastBusConfig section it returns null, yet for the TestConfig section I get an objet back ok...

```
var unicastBusConfigSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("UnicastBusConfig") as UnicastBusConfigSection;
var unicastBusConfigSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("TestConfig") as UnicastBusConfigSection;
```

Comment: Does `GetSection` return `null`, or does your `as` return `null`? Try `object x = `GetSection(...)` to see which is `null`

Comment: Hi John, its the as which is returning null - commenting that out returns an object ok...

Comment: So the problem is that your object is not of the type you thought it was. Find out what type is is, and you'll have made a huge leap forward.

Comment: But when I instead call GetSection on the TestConfig section it works ok, casting to the exact same type of object as the UnicastBusConfig attempt. The only difference I see between them is the type as defined in the config section name.

Comment: They are not the same type. `<TestConfig>` is of type `Console1.UnicastBusConfigSection`, but `<UnicastBusConfig>` is of type `NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig`.

Comment: You don't need to add your own version of these `ConfigurationSection` derived classes - just use the ones from the `NServiceBus.Core` assembly. They're `public`.